# Display Image from source folder

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm trying to display images that are stored in the source folder of my project.
However when i try to display them using

```html
<img src="Image.png" alt="Displaying Image">
```

It simply shows me the alt text instead of the image. I've tried absolute path aswell but that does not change anything either.

I've searched other threads but nothing made me figure out what my problem is even though this seems simple.

Thanks in advance

Jan

Comment: you would need to share your folder structure in order for us to help.

Comment: It's a fresh created asp.net mvc application with the image in the source folder of the project. I checked that with "Server.MapPath("~");"

Comment: if you go to `http://yoursite.com/Image.png` does it load?  because it depends on the page you declare it on.  if it's in a sub path, you probably just need to be more specific and say `src="/Image.png"`

Comment: thanks the / fixed it for me that stupid error cost me several hours and it would've been some more without you. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a "/". My path should've been like this:

```
<img src="/Image.png" alt="Displaying Image"
```